# Geny Motion get disappear

Tags: android, android-emulator, genymotion, genymotion-gps

I was using Genymotion perfectly, but from the last few days when I start my Genymotion and turn on it's GPS, suddenly my Genymotion disappears. But my eclipse shows that Genymotion is running, but I am unable to locate Genymotion. Advice?

Comment: just delete the settings of genymotion and recreate it and run. It might work again :)

Answer (score 1):

Rest Genymotion emulator.

- Right click on Genymotion virtual device which device has problem.
- Then select option -> Reset this device to factory state.

Screen shot[image]

Comment: I am using free version of Genymotion and reset to factory state option is not available for free version.

Comment: @OmjiMehrotra Use first option to reset.It available on free version.